# Importing a component from another JS file using React

Tags: reactjs, import, export

I am learning how to use components using React.

My page works fine, but if I move a component to another JS file and attempt to import it, my page goes completely blank.

Here is the working code where the imports are commented out.

```
//import Header from "./Header.js"
//import Footer from "./Footer.js"


function Body () {
        return (
                <div>
                        <h1>Reasons I am excited to learn react</h1>        
                        <ol>Reasons
                                <li>Popular</li>
                                <li>Functional</li>
                                <li>I can build apps</li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
        )
}


function Page() {
        return (
                <div>
                        {/* <Header /> */}
                        <Body />
                        {/* <Footer /> */}
                </div>
        )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

and here is the Header I am trying to import

```
export default function Header () {
    return (
            <header>
                    <nav className="nav">
                            <img className="nav-image" src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/React-icon.svg" />
                            <ul className="nav-items">
                                    <li>Pricing</li>
                                    <li>About</li>
                                    <li>Contact</li>
                            </ul>
                    
                    </nav>
            </header>
    )
}
```

There is no error message when the lines are uncommented, but when I open the HTML document the page, which displayed before, is always blank.

Why is it that when I uncomment either of the import lines from the top, my page renders completely blank?

Update: It looks like it is a general problem with import; if I add:

```
import React from 'react';
```

to the top, it also makes the page render as a blank white screen.

Per recommendation in the comments, I put it in an online editor (Code Sand Box), and the code works fine there. I guess the problem is with how I have Visual Studio Code set up?? I was using live server and then tried to use npm, but didn't quite figure out how to get npm to render the page.

Comment: Whats the error in console ?

Comment: Hello, it would help others to answer your question if you could share the files structure of your app, maybe the "build" system you are using (Create-React-App for exemple) and the error you got in console.

Comment: @LokeshKumarMeena there is no error in the console.

Comment: @Zoleas I don't understand what you mean by "share the files structure of your app." What is the "build" system.

Comment: What are the file names of Header and footer ?

Comment: @LokeshKumarMeena Header.js and Footer.js

Comment: I tried to replicate it and it works fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bose-qktgu5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @DazlyGonsalves does that mean the problem might be my environment? I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @DavidBenMoshe No, that is not the problem; you might receive an error using any Text Editor. Something could surely be figured out if you could specify some error from the terminal or the browser console.

Comment: @DavidBenMoshe for the files structure, I mean the folder where your project is, how are the files stored in it (it could also be a screen shot of the Explorer tab in VS Code). for the build system, I mean the tools you are using to create and run your app. How did you create your project (vitejs, create-react-app, etc.), how do you run it (yarn, npm, etc.) ?

Comment: @DazlyGonsalves there was no error in either the terminal or the browser, the everything looked fine except for the page rendering as blank when I tried to import something. I also put the exact same code in an online editor (codesandbox) and it worked fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this import:

```
import Header from "./Header"
```

Maybe show your folder structure, if it is not working.

Comment: The same thing happens with import Header from "./Header" All the files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Change above line as below

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
          <React.StrictMode>
              <Page />
          </React.StrictMode>
        );
```

Comment: I get the exact same problem. When I replace that line with the new code, my page only displays a white screen and there are no errors.

Comment: can you write ur code on any online editor and send a link

Comment: I just copied all the files to codesandbox, and it renders fine. I guess I don't understand how to use React in Visual Studio Code...

Comment: Need to see your file structure and react versions and other stuff